# Viewport not working at all

Tags: android, iphone, viewport

I have a very weird problem with the viewport tag which is driving me nuts..

I am basing my examples on this article: http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/an-introduction-to-meta-viewport-and-viewport/

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=320">
</head>
<body>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean nec tortor turpis, id pharetra purus. Pellentesque venenatis tortor vitae metus varius placerat. Donec eu dui id turpis egestas lobortis.
</body>
</html>
```

Now, I am watching this page on iPhone and Android. What I should see on both phones is the text, with on portait mode, the first line ending with consectetur, and in landscape mode, the first line also ending with consectetur, but with a larger text.

What I see is this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qO5Jt.jpg

First image (Xn5r7ef), iPhone portrait
Second image (mYNvAGR), iPhone landscape
Third image (7wqmCAX), Android portrait
Fouth  image (sFuyxlc), Android landscape

As can be seen, the android does not resize the text, it simply keeps text same size and uses the extra width to display more text. From the dev opera link I have understood that this should not be happening.

If I use width=device-width, both phones keep showing exactly the same text as the imgur photos, meaning that in this case, the iPhone is not displaying the text correctly.

What am I doing wrong here? Am I doing something wrong? How can I get this to work correctly?

Obviously, my real project is a lot larger, but I am having similar meta viewport hell problems... problems, the page seems zoomed in too much, on every page load, different pages (with exactly the same viewport meta tag) have different zoom

Answer (score 0):

To my surprise, I can confirm both the described Android (https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQJ4j.jpg) and iPhone behavior (https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5IBU.jpg) by using the examples on http://andreasbovens.github.com/understanding-viewport/

These problems are new to me, and must be recent regressions in the Android Browser and Mobile Safari... Chrome and Opera Mobile behave as they should.

Very annoying bugs indeed: you can work around the iPhone issue by using `initial-scale=1`. I don't have a workaround for the Android problem. Investigating.